# Using :before and sprite background images

Tags: html, css, background-image, pseudo-element

Trying to use `:before` on a span to add a background image off the edge of the main content.

Essentially should look like this:

[image]

I have the triangle as a bg image but can't seem to make it sit right, or show at all.

See JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y6rMs/1/

Answer (score 2):

You could do this without an image at all if you wanted to

http://jsfiddle.net/Y6rMs/26/

```
#bottomWide span.ribbon:before {
    content: "";
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left: -40px;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 40px solid #0099ff; 
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

Here is a list of some of the other shapes you can create with css
http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: What is the support for this? IE?

Comment: `:before` and `:after` are only supported in IE8+ the other major browsers shouldn't have a problem.  Here is a nice chart: http://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/

Answer (score 0):

I got it to [show up here](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/Y6rMs/5/), I think you can get the rest...
I added `display: block;` and removed your background-position rule.

Comment: A few other fixes : http://jsfiddle.net/3MhZt/ (moved the background from the .ribbon to the a, added a margin for position).

Answer (score 0):

Here it is
[jsfiddle.net/trajce/Y6rMs/27/](http://jsfiddle.net/trajce/Y6rMs/27/)

```
#bottomWide span.ribbon{
    position:relative;
    background-color:#C1C976;
    padding:5px 2%;
    float:right; 
}
#bottomWide span.ribbon:before{
    content:'';
    height:38px;
    width:25px;
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/7nrYgTn.png);
    background-position:center left; <-
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:absolute; 
    top:0;
    left:-30px; <- just play with this values a bit
    height:40px; <-
    width:30px; <-
}
```

Comment: There is, i dont know how you cant see it. Checking wrong fiddle or maybe you should clear your browser cache.

Comment: Okay.. seemed to be a cache issue with jsfiddle. Once I loaded the image separately it started appearing... disregard.